# JSF rendered doesn't work

Tags: jsf

I am developing an application using JSF. I want when user logins to the page, to show a message saying "hello". Each time an user is loged correctly with its credentials user's id is stored in currentUser attribute.

if user does not login and access to my page writing in the browser the URL (not having an user id), to show a message saying "You have no rigths to access this page". What am I doing wrong?
This is the code to show the message

```
<h:form rendered="#{usersManagedBean.currentUser ne null}">
     <h:outputText value=" hello " />
 </h:form>
 <h:form rendered="#{usersManagedBean.currentUser eq null}">
     <h:outputText value="You have no rigths to access this page" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: `#{not empty usersManagedBean.currentUser}` corresponds to both `not null` and `!=''`. Try doing it and also check, if `usersManagedBean.currentUser` is correctly set in the associated backing bean depending upon different user's actions.

Comment: Which of the outputs is rendered?

Answer (score 0):

instead use the Empty Operator

```
<h:form rendered="#{not empty usersManagedBean.currentUser}">
    <h:outputText value=" hello " />
</h:form>
<h:form rendered="#{empty usersManagedBean.currentUser}">
    <h:outputText value="You have no rigths to access this page" />
</h:form>
```

Empty operator found in [EL 2.2 specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html)

```
    1.10 Empty Operator - empty A

       The empty operator is a prefix operator that can be used to determine if a value is null or empty.


    To evaluate empty A

    If A is null, return true
    Otherwise, if A is the empty string, then return true
    Otherwise, if A is an empty array, then return true
    Otherwise, if A is an empty Map, return true
    Otherwise, if A is an empty Collection, return true
    Otherwise return false
```